# Define types in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, computer-science

If I have the types:

```
type test = float * float

type helper =
| test1 of test
| test2 of test
| test3 of test
```

And right now I have a function with the type:

```
f: ('a * 'b) -> ('b -> 'a) -> 'a
```

What will the type of `f(helper(1., 2.), true)` be? Will it be something like:

```
(helper * bool) -> (bool -> helper) -> helper
```

Or am I still confused with the polymorphic type in OCaml.

Answer (score 2):

A value of type `helper` would be constructed with `test1`, `test2`, or `test3`, which must begin with a capital letter.

```
type test = float * float

type helper =
| Test1 of test
| Test2 of test
| Test3 of test
```

If we then test `f (Test1 (1., 2.), true)`, we have partially applied `f` and get a function which takes a function argument and returns `helper`, or a type signature of:

```
(bool -> helper) -> helper
```

Comment: So if I have another function `fun te st -> f (te, st)`, it will have the same type as f does, right?

Comment: That function should have type `'a -> 'b -> ('b -> 'a) -> 'a`